# Input in HTML not connecting to PHP post method

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML input and button:

```
            <form action="validate.php" method="post">
        <!-- THE CODE INSERT -->
        <div id="code">
            <form>
                <label></label>
                <input id="input" name="InputText" type="text"/>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- THE BUTTON ITSELF -->
        <input type="button" id="button" name="myButton"><b>Search Archive</b>

        </form>
```

in my `validate.php` file I have this switch statement:

```
    <?php 

switch ($_POST["InputText"])
{
        case "someval": 
            http_header("someaddress.com");
            die();
            break;
}

 ?>
```

the problem is that when I click the button it doesn't do anything. I did this with JS and it worked but it should be noted that I'm really new to web development so if anyone can explain to me what I did wrong and specifically why that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Nested forms are [invalid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). I would start by correcting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form inside of a form, that won't work. Also, you need to include an `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` before you close your form. This is what submits the information from the form to your `action="file.php"`.

A form would typically look like this:

**file.html**

```
<form action="validate.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you'd do something like this:

**validate.php**

```
<?php

echo "Your username is" . $_POST['username'];
```

The `$_POST['username']` is the data gathered from the `name="username"` input from the HTML. If you write `die($_POST);` you'll get all the data that is sent through the form.

Comment: but I want it to redirect, if I write `die($_POST)` is it still going to do that?

Comment: No if you use die(var_dump($_POST)); you can inspect all the data inside the $_POST. It's used for testing purposes, not something you use inside your code on production.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using type='button' you have to perform the submit by yourself. 
So, you can do that using javascript or change to type='submit'.
Example:

```
<input type="button" id="button" name="myButton"><b>Search Archive</b>
```

To

```
<input type="submit" id="button" name="myButton" value="Search Archive" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
   <form action="/validate.php" method="post">
    <!-- THE CODE INSERT -->
    <div id="code">

            <label></label>
            <input id="input" name="InputText" type="text"/>

    </div>

    <!-- THE BUTTON ITSELF -->

    <button type="submit" id="button" name="myButton">Search Archive</button>


    </form>
```

in the div id ="code" you used form tag that's why its not work...delete it will work and button type must be submit